# Rich Texts Not saved the Data

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

i got issues in Saving Data in Rich Texts .. I already make the setAttributes for each attribute  and have no changes too !
it is my code

attributes

```
attributes :{
    titleONEHOMEPorT: {
        type: "string",
        source: "html",
        selector: "h2",
      },
      titleTwoHOMEPorT: {
        type: "string",
        source: "html",
        selector: "h2",
      },
},
```

'Attributes and setAttributes'

```
 const {titleONEHOMEPorT , titleTwoHOMEPorT} = attributes;
            function onChangeTitleOnePort(newporttitone) { setAttributes({ titleONEHOMEPorT: newporttitone }); }
```

and this is the rich text in return

```
                            <RichText  key="editable" tagName="h2"  placeholder="اخر" value={titleONEHOMEPorT} onChange={onChangeTitleOnePort} />
```

And there's no thing shows in Console .. and not stored in DB Too

Comment: Can you please share the code of your `save()` function?

Comment: @S.Walsh
save({ attributes }) {
  
    return null;
    //render in PHP 
    }

Comment: @S.Walsh and it also doesn't passed to render Callback Function in php

Comment: Please see answer below, if the suggested solution does not work for you, please provide more detail about why/what you are using PHP for to render the content.

Answer (score 0):

The `RichText` component requires [saving the content](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/richtext/#example) in `save()` with  `<RichText.Content ... />`. By implementing the `save()` function to return null, the content is not saved into HTML. The way the RichText component works is by using the *selector* set in attributes to parse content from the saved *source* (HTML). If there is no content saved into the post content as HTML, nothing can load.

Using the PHP `render_callback` for dynamic blocks is intended for dynamic content. As you mention this is your current approach, if you are using PHP to do some dynamic string replacement or something similiar, perhaps what you could try instead is using [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) hook to alter the content after its retrieved from the database but before its displayed on the frontend. By using this approach, you can implement the required `save()` function for `RichText` to work and have the content saved and edited via the Editor while making full use of `RichText` features.

Comment: I'm really appreciate that caring and i understand well this answer .. I'm just was using the reach text to make the header of this block can changed in the same place ..  but i thought may i use another input maybe be in Panel body and make the changes .. but if i do it i will oki maybe save the data but attributes still not showing in Render Callback function .. the array equals null , it's not have the names or values of attributes  , btw i will try to make this changes in panels body and try again

Comment: @Yusuf Happy to help! If you are trying to add content to Panel Body, then maybe the [TextControl](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/text-control/) is a better component to use. This way you can easily save strings of text to attributes and use those values in PHP `render_callback`.

Comment: yes , I'm tryin to do it right now

Comment: Still not work , even with Text Control .. The Npm When rendering the TextControl got a Error Decoder .. i will rebuild it again and again :) :) .. 
Btw thank you for helpin me !